# DirectX 11 glGetUniformLocation / gluniform

Tags: c++, shader, webgl, directx

hello i I am trying to make my 3d object to move. I added custom (float3 offset) to .hlsl file and sum it in output.pos.

Now I have to access pointer to this data (float3 offset) and add a specified value. So it ends up in changing value output.pos for every vertex.

In WeBGL there is a way to make it using

```
offset = glGetUniformLocation(shader,"offset");
gl.uniform3f(offset, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

But I am using DirectX11 and I have no idea if this is possible.
Can someone answer this question?

Comment: `glGetUniformLocation` is an OpenGL API function. It is not WebGL and not DirectX.

Comment: DirectX uses so-called Constant Buffers instead of Uniforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ DirectX 11 glGetUniformLocation equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338532/c-directx-11-glgetuniformlocation-equivalent)